# Why does not while loop stop?

Tags: c#, while-loop

```
int Coins = 27;
int playersInput =0;
int counter = 0;

while (Coins >= 0) {
            
    Console.WriteLine("There are " +  (Coins - playersInput)  + " in the bag" + "\n");
    Console.WriteLine("Turn #" + (counter + 1));
    playersInput += Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    if (playersInput % 2 == 0) {
       Console.WriteLine("Player 0 turn");
    } else {
       Console.WriteLine("Player 1 turn");
    }
    counter++;            
}

Console.WriteLine("The last player lost this game");
```

The code has to alternate between two players and if the `coins` value reaches to `0` it has to print the `console.writeline` that is outside the `while` loop and I don't want to use `break`.

Answer (score 2):

You never update `Coins` and the number of coins left in the jar is `Coins - playersInput`.

```
while ((Coins - playersInput) >= 0)
```